# Make file available in chrome from vue project in VS Code

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, svg, visual-studio-code, three.js

I'm generally new to web development so bear with me

I am using threejs and want to load an svg into this using the SVGLoader example but thats not really what my question is about. The function for the svg loading takes a path so what I need is to make the svg file I want to load available somewhere that can be accessed via a path.  What I can't workout is how to tell vs code to make file available that isn't referenced anywhere.  Whereever I put the files in my folder structure in vs code, it never ends up in the folders in chrome and so I can't reference the file via a path.

I may be misunderstanding something but is there a way of telling vs code to include certain files and copy them over?

for reference, I'm using typescript, vue/vuetify/vuex and threejs in a pane

so need a valid path here:

```
loadSvgResource('/static-assets/node_selected.svg',(o) => {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (i seem to do this a lot!)

in the [vue documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#disable-index-generation) it says to place any files needed in this way in the public folder which I have done and then I have added this to the index.html in public for each file:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>static-assets/node_selected.svg" >
```

and the file is here: `public/static-assets/node_selected.svg` in vs code

then when I come to use the file in the code I am doing this:

```
aFunction(process.env.BASE_URL + 'static-assets/node_selected.svg')
```

and that seems to work